# Is there a 'better' tuning frequency than 440 Hz?

Tags: acoustics, resonance, harmonics

My apologize if this question is a bit broad or open ended but I'm asking here rather than a music forum for two reasons:

1. I'm trying to gain a better understanding of the physics of sound
   and acoustics
2. From my understanding the decision to make 440 Hz standard tuning was largely arbitrary, and the argument for 432 Hz is based on metaphysical nonsense, but I've yet to see a physics backed argument for any other frequency.

That being said, the idea that one tuning frequency may better resonate with common physical medians than another (and potentially sound better to the human ear) doesn't seem entirely farfetched to me. My intuition tells me that rather than there being a single 'ideal' tuning frequency, it's likely complicated and situational. Which explains why 440 Hz is so broadly accepted as a simple answer, but I'd still love to learn more about what is known about the topic and how to approach a question like this.

Comment: The history is complicated, but ultimately it's arbitrary.

Comment: If you allow choice between two pieces with similar tuning, listeners reliably prefer the higher pitched version.  So there's no "ideal".  440 is just a standard, and it's not driven by any physics principles.

Comment: You're right in saying that the 440Hz tuning was basically arbitrary. Both in past and in fact in present there are many tuning standards around. It's more dominant in recent times because in 1955 it was recognized as the global standard. But even so in that decision they relied on precedent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited to [music.se] where the reasoning behind the "standard" 440Hz choice is better understood.  There are, however, [many other approaches to tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_tuning).